# Any reason why a model's fields not updating despite an update call?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel 5.3 I am, using Model events to take certain actions. For the most part, things are working fine, just one place in the program flow where data is not updating.

Here is the whole story:

I have a database structure with `courses` and `weeks`. So Course 1 with Week1, Week2, etc.

Then to repeat a given course I also have `courseinstance` and `weekinstance` which contain date info for given instances of courses and weeks.

I am using Angular in the backend to handle CRUD, and when I create a `course` it automatically creates a `courseinstance` where a `start_date` and `end_date` are null.

The code for that in the `course` API controller is

```
$thiscourse=  \App\Courses::create(Input::all());
```

After that the `course` model executes this:

```
public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($course) {

        // add first instance of this course - dates will be null at this point
        $instance = new Coursesinstance;
        $instance->course_id = $course->id;
        $instance->save();
    });
}
```

That is successful. Then in my backend, I add a week to the course (which is for descriptive data about the week's topic) and that creates a first instance of the week where there are a start and end date. In the API `week` controller first we have this:

```
$week = \App\Week::create(Input::all());
```

Then that triggers `create` event on the model and we go to:

```
static::created(function($week) {

    // add first instance of this week
    $instance = new Weekinstance;
    $instance->week_id = $week->id;
    $instance->weekstart = $week->weekstart;
    $instance->zoomstart = $week->zoomstart;

    $coursesinstance_id = DB::table('coursesinstance')
                            ->select('id')
                            ->where('course_id', $week->courses->id)
                            ->first();

    $instance->coursesinstance_id = $coursesinstance_id->id;
    $instance->save();
});
```

This is a success, things looking fine in the database, all relationships proper, various id's just as they should be.

Now since a new week instance is created, we go to this in the Weekinstance model so that I can look at all weeks in the instance and update the course instance start and end dates.

```
static::created(function($weekinstance) {

    // get all week instances corresponding to this course instance

    $weekinstances = DB::table('weekinstance')
                        ->select('*')
                        ->where('coursesinstance_id', $weekinstance->coursesinstance_id)
                        ->get();

    $weekstarts=array();
    foreach ($weekinstance as $instance)
    {
        $weekstart = $instance->weekstart;
        $weekstarts[].=$weekstart;
    }

    $dates = array_map('strtotime', $weekstarts);
    $startdate = min($dates);
    $enddate = strtotime("+7 day", max($dates));
    // update start and end date for the course instance
    $result = \App\Coursesinstance::where('id', $weekinstance->coursesinstance_id)
                            ->update([
                                'start_date' => $startdate, 
                                'end_date' => $enddate
                            ]);    
});
```

And here is where things break down. The `week` is successfully created, the `weekinstance` is created, but the `update` call above just doesn't set the `start_date` and `end_date` of the `courseinstance`.

I have ran in a debugger, and at the moment of the update, all seems well. A `$startdate` and `$enddate` variable are created as timestamps, the where clause is indeed returning the course instance, the return result is a 1, so Laravel is not returning any errors, and in log file no issues. `start_date` and `end_date` are fillable on the model. Everything truly looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

The date fields are are stored as `TIMESTAMP` in MySQL. It does not accept Unix timestamp's as an argument. So you must convert the timestamp's into the correct format, before updating. One way to do this:

```
->update([
     'start_date' => Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($startdate), 
     'end_date' => Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($enddate)
]);
```

Comment: Yeah, I also realized this just a minute ago. I just used PHP function to format the timestamp. thanks for showing this approach using Carbon

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after spending so much time on this I finally realized the problem is that I was passing my `timestamp` values directly to the query builder. Little did I know that MYSQL expects a `timestamp` as a date string. I thought the data type `datetime` was meant for strings and that a `timestamp`, as name suggests, could be used for an actual `timestamp`. Crazy thinking, I know.

So here is how I had to create the "timestamps":

```
$startdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',min($dates));
$enddate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+7 day", max($dates)));
```

So in other words, 180 degrees away from what I would consider logical based on definition of a timestamp.

Thanks,
Brian